# big \tableofcontents - bottom margin not working

Tags: table-of-contents, margins, geometry

When creating the table of contents via:

```
\tableofcontents
```

The bottom margin is not working (see screenshot). The other margins seem to work. Do you have any ideas what could went wrong?

[image: bottom margin wrong]
Example to reproduce the problem with my custom settings:

```
%-----------------------------------
% Define document and include general packages
%-----------------------------------
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=4cm, right=2cm, top=4cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}      %Positionierung von Abb. und Tabellen mit [H] erzwingen
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\pdfminorversion=7
\usepackage{times}
\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont

\usepackage[raggedright,bf,sf]{titlesec}

\usepackage[hang, multiple]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{1em}

% Biblatex
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
citestyle=authoryear-ibid,
url=false,
isbn=false,
notetype=footonly,
hyperref=false,
sortlocale=de]{biblatex}

%-----------------------------------
% Zeilenabstand 1,5-zeilig
%-----------------------------------
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

%-----------------------------------
% Absätze durch eine neue Zeile
%-----------------------------------
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.8em plus 0.5em minus 0.3em}

\sloppy                 %Abstände variieren
\pagestyle{headings}

%-----------------------------------
% define header area
%-----------------------------------
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
% Kopfzeile rechts: Seitenzahl
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}     
% kein Footer vorhanden                     
%\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

%-----------------------------------
% Document Start
%-----------------------------------
\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{"}

\pagenumbering{Roman}                               % Seitennumerierung auf römisch umstellen
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}    % Neuer Tabellen-Spalten-Typ: %Zentriert und umbrechbar

%-----------------------------------
% Titlepage
%-----------------------------------
\begin{titlepage}
    \newgeometry{left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm}
    \begin{center}
        Dummy
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

%-----------------------------------
% Table of Contents
%-----------------------------------
\tableofcontents
\newpage

%-----------------------------------
% Content
%-----------------------------------
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\section{dummy}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}

\section{dummy}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}

\section{dummy}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}

\section{dummy}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}

\section{dummy}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}

\section{dummy}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}

\section{dummy}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}

\section{dummy}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}

\section{dummy}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}

\section{dummy}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}
\subsection{dummysub}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome back to TeX.SE! Please make your code into a complete example that reproduces the issue. You can just add a number of empty sections to populate the table of contents. Also try to minimize the preamble by removing packages that are not related to the issue, for example I don't think the `svg` package is relevant, or `marvosym`, or `times` and probably several others. This will make your code easier to read and debug. You might even find the problem yourself during the efforts to minimize the code.

Comment: fancyhdr is not recommended with this documentclass. Also better use koma script commands then geometry package

Comment: With your code snippet it is not possible to reproduce your problem. Please, edit your question and add a short but complete example showing your issue.

Comment: Hi, ive edited my question and inserted an example to reproduce the problem. @Maeve What do i use instead of fanyhdr? What do you mean with koma script command then geometry package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `\restoregeometry` after the title page.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=4cm, right=2cm, top=4cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \newgeometry{left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm}
    \begin{center}
        Dummy
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry% <- added

\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\subsection{dummysub}\blindtext
\subsection{dummysub}\blindtext
\subsection{dummysub}\blindtext
\subsection{dummysub}\blindtext
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

Additional remarks:

- Remove package `titlesec`.
- Replace `\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}\setlength{\parskip}{0.8em plus 0.5em minus 0.3em}` by `\setparsizes{0mm}{0.8em plus 0.5em minus 0.3em}{0pt plus 1fil}`.
- Load package `hyperref` as the last one.
- It is suggested to use package `scrlayer-scrpage` with KOMA-Script classes for header and footer.
- `\pagenumbering` resets the page counter automatically. So you can remove `\setcounter{page}{1}`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solved my problem. I've also made some changes based on your additional remarks.